# Flutter Firebase login function

Tags: firebase, flutter, function, dart

How to access if users exist on users/$usersUids[index]

```
_db.collection('users').doc(user1.uid).set({
    "displayName": user1.displayName,
    "email": user1.email,
    "uid": user1.uid,
    'date': date,
    "photoUrl": user1.photoURL,
    "lastSignIn": DateTime.now(), 
  });
```

or if the user has already login/signup then I want to run

```
_db.collection('users').doc(user1.uid).set({
    "displayName": user1.displayName,
    "email": user1.email,
    "uid": user1.uid,
    'date': date,
    "photoUrl": user1.photoURL,
    "lastSignIn": DateTime.now(),
    'favItems': []
  });
```

If the question is wrong then please fix this
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use Firebase Auth?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If a document is created when the user account is first created then it will always exist so those two examples state the same thing 'if user exists' and 'already has login` - e.g. if a user exists they will have a login... and... they will have a login if they exist. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: question is clear also i provide image below and solved this issue now if any one required solution then temm me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use firebase authentication to see if the user is logged in, you will need to set that up in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).  Here's a video I used to help me set it up: [Flutter Authentication with Email and Password Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7tt8CeMnhs)  Below is an example of what your code may look like once you have the authentication set up.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth.currentUser;

    // CHECK LOGIN STATUS OF USER AND DECIDE WHICH SCREEN TO SHOW USER
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (user != null) {
      // SHOW THE USERS PERSONAL HOME PAGE
      currentScreen = 1;
    } else {
      // USER IS NOT LOGGED IN, SHOW THE SIGN IN SCREEN
      currentScreen = 2;
    }
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything else for you.

Comment: Thank you . please view this firebase image. https://ibb.co/28R2gnL    where i set({ user details for 1st time. my question is if user already login and also user have usergoogleAuthid on users/usersAuthDocIds than i want to set({ with differents value thank you